how to interpret typescript class member using square brackets
I came across the following code snippet while reading some documentation...can someone explain to me how to interpret the following declaration of y within square brackets, at first I thought this was array destructuring, but that does not seem right...
class x {
  [y: string]: any;
  constructor(public uid: string) {}
}

I want to mention this is a class defn, not an interface...I do understand how to interpret this in an interface like below
interface Isomething {
    [x: string]: any;
}


That's specifying it accepts any string key and the type of the value is any. The name y doesn't really matter.
